# How do I run emacs from the version of emacs in Emacs.app?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, emacs

I've downloaded emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com to run as a windowed app. This way I don't have to install XCode and then install it from homebrew. The problem is that running mixed version of emacs isn't helpful for my .emacs file. There are certain features (e.g. package.el) that work out of the box in emacs versions 24+ but require some package installation for other versions.

**How do I run `emacs` from Terminal in a way that uses the Emacs.app version of emacs?**

I want it to run in Terminal, not as a windowed app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/Applications/Emacs/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw
```